# Install Google Chrome extension through Windows registry does not work in some computers?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, registry

I created registry entry to set up Google Chrome extension,

```
Type: string
Name: update_url
Value: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx
```

in following registry locations,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc
```

The computer is Windows 10 64bit with Google Chrome 64bit. But this only works in some computers. In other computers with same Windows 10 64bit with Google Chrome 64bit it does not work. What is the issue?

Comment: Are they also using [64-bit of Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/63tCYeuMzGE) like you?

Comment: Yes, their using the same.